# Vue directive to set or modify element property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I have plenty elements like that:

```
<some-custom-component
  :errors="formErrors.has(getErrorKey('town'))"
  :error-messages="formErrors.getAll(getErrorKey('town'))"
></some-custom-component>
```

Property `formErrors` and function `getErrorKey` achieved by mixin.
I've tried to create a directive to reduce this div definition. I want something like that:

```
<some-custom-component v-errorable="'town'"></some-custom-component>
```

But I stucked with that.

```
// errorable.js
export default {
  name: 'errorable',
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    // What should I write this to achive this?
  }
}
```

UPD: I think I should provide more info. `formErrors` is computed value and `getErrorKey` is method which returns key to check (in most ways it will be the same as provided paramether 'town' -> 'town' etc.)

Answer (score 2):

try code below:

```
export default {
  name: 'errorable',
  componentUpdated (el, binding, vNode) {
    let {formErrors,getErrorKey} = vNode.context,
        {value} = binding
    el.setAttribute('errors',formErrors.has(getErrorKey(value)))
    el.setAttribute('error-messages',formErrors.getAll(getErrorKey(value)))
  }
}
```

Comment: It just an example. I'm using Vuetify with `v-text-field` which could show errors if there some. Btw, our your suggestion is not correct - code doesn't works.

Comment: If you try to use it on a component, it sure won't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problem like this:

```
export default {
name: 'errorable',
bind(el, binding, vNode) {
    let { formErrors, getErrorKey } = vNode.context,
        { value } = binding

    //with v-text-field's props 'error-messages'(Array) works correctly, I did it for my proj
    Vue.set(el.__vue__._props.errorMessages,
        el.__vue__._props.errorMessages.length,
        ...formErrors.getAll(getErrorKey(value)));

    //if attribute 'errors' is array
    Vue.set(el.__vue__._props.errors,
        el.__vue__._props.errorMessages.length,
        ...formErrors.has(getErrorKey(value)));

    //if you mean about 'error'(Boolean) - props for v-text-field in vuetify, but row below probably get warning
    Vue.set(el.__vue__._props, 'error', formErrors.has(getErrorKey(value)));
}}
```

Comment: This way is not correct: `[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.`